# wacom CTL-472 installation on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (build failure issue)

Tags: drivers, wacom

I tried to install drivers for wacom CTL-472 on my laptop that runs with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

I tried most of the suggestions I found on internet. None of them worked.

For example, I visited https://linuxwacom.github.io/

1. I opened https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source I ran `sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and got the following output

   > Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
   >   Reading state information... Done
   >   build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
   >   autoconf is already the newest version (2.69-11).
   >   linux-headers-4.15.0-72-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0-72.81).
   >   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2. Then, as mentioned there, I opened https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/releases, downloaded **input-wacom-0.45.0.tar.bz2** and extracted
3. Then I run `if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"`
   and got this output:

> bash: ./configure: No such file or directory Build Failed

Running xinput list gives following output

```
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Truevision HD: HP Truevision           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

How to I solve the build failure and proceed to solve this?

The page https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Device-IDs says that "The "Linux" column indicates that minimum kernel version that natively supports the tablet". Further it says "You can check your kernel version by running uname -r". I did that and found that, kernel is "4.15.0-72-generic" (please see attached pic below) where as according to that page, kernel should be minimum 4.16 (please see attached pic below).

[image]

I think that could be a problem. How do I solve this?

---

I have checked at https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Device-IDs to see if my device is supported. It turns out that it does. I am attaching the screenshot.

[image]

---

I am also adding screenshots of the downloaded folder (with location).

[image]

Screenshot of contents of the folder is below

[image]

For ./configure I got following response.

[image]

screenshot for configure permission is below.

[image]

History of what I have done is mentioned below:

```
 1506  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1507  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:doctormo/wacom-plus
 1508  sudo apt-get update
 1509  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 1510  sudo apt-get install wacom-dkms
 1511  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1512  clear
 1513  sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 1514  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1515  wacom
 1516  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1517  sudo apt-get install autoconf pkg-config make xutils-dev libtool xserver-xorg-dev$(dpkg -S $(which Xorg) | grep -Eo -- "-hwe-[^:]*") libx11-dev libxi-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libudev-dev
 1518  set -- --prefix="/usr" --libdir="$(readlink -e $(ls -d /usr/lib*/xorg/modules/input/../../../ | head -n1))"
 1519  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh "$@"; else ./configure "$@"; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1520  clear
 1521  sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
 1522  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 1523  sudo apt-get update
 1524  sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
 1525  sudo do-release-upgrade
 1526  sudo ./bionic &
 1527  xsetwacom --list devices 
 1528  sudo rmmod wacom
 1529  sudo rmmod wacom_w8001
 1530  $ if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1531  clear
 1532  sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 1533  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1534  grep "" /sys/module/wacom*/version
 1535  sudo rmmod wacom
 1536  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1537  xinput list
 1538  clear
 1539  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential 
 1540  sudo apt-get install autoconf                                  
 1541  cd downloads
 1542  cd /downloads
 1543  cd /home
 1544  /downloads
 1545  cd /home
 1546  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1547  modinfo wacom | grep version
 1548  sudo -s 'apt-get update && apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom'
 1549  sudo apt  install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 1550  sudo apt-get install git-core make kernel-package bc
 1551  ls home
 1552  ls /home
 1553  ls Desktop
 1554  cd input-wacom-0.45.0
 1555  /configure
 1556  ./configure
 1557  make
 1558  sudo make install
 1559  clear
 1560  sudo apt install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 1561  cd Desktop
 1562  home
 1563  cd Desktop
 1564  sudo apt install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 1565  ./configure
 1566  sh ./configure
 1567  xinput list
 1568  uname -r
 1569  cd Desktop
 1570  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1571  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
 1572  sudo apt-get install ukuu
 1573  sudo xhost +
 1574  sudo ukuu
 1575  sudo ukuu --install-latest
 1576  clear
 1577  sudo apt-get update
 1578  sudo apt-get install python-bs4 python-apt
 1579  cd /tmp
 1580  rm -rf medigeek-kmp*
 1581  wget https://github.com/medigeek/kmp-downloader/tarball/master -O kmpd.tar.gz
 1582  tar xzf kmpd.tar.gz
 1583  cd medigeek-*
 1584  python kmpd.py -d
 1585  uname -r
 1586  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
 1587  clear
 1588  uname -r
 1589  lsb_release -a
 1590  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04  
 1591  clear
 1592  lsb_release -a
 1593  uname -mrs
 1594  sudo apt update
 1595  apt-cache search linux-generic
 1596  sudo apt install linux-image-4.xx
 1597  apt-cache search linux-image
 1598  sudo apt install linux-image-4.xx
 1599  clear
 1600  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
 1601  sudo apt-get update
 1602  sudo apt-get install ukuu -y
 1603  ukuu –help
 1604  uname -mrs
 1605  uname -r
 1606  clear
 1607  sudo apt-get autoremove
 1608  ukuu --list
 1609  ukuu
 1610  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 1611  do-releaseupgrade -c
 1612  do-release-upgrade -c
 1613  /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
 1614  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1615  apt install linux-image-generic
 1616  apt purge linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
 1617  hwe-support-status
 1618  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1619  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1620  clear
 1621  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 1622  sudo do-release-upgrade -p
 1623  sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 1624  lsb_release -a
 1625  sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 1626  clear
 1627  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1628  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 1629  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1630  sudo apt-get clean
 1631  sudo apt-get autoclean
 1632  sudo apt-get -f install
 1633  clear
 1634  sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
 1635  clear
 1636  sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
 1637  clear
 1638  sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
 1639  mkdir ppa-purge && cd ppa-purge && wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/ppa-purge/ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr56_all.deb && wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/a/aptitude/aptitude_0.6.6-1ubuntu1_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i ./*.deb
 1640  sudo ppa-purge ppa:someppa/ppa
 1641  apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
 1642  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
 1643  clear
 1644  sudo apt-get update
 1645  sudo apt-get upgrade
 1646  sudo apt --fix-broken install
 1647  sudo apt-get update
 1648  lsb_release -a
 1649  uname -mrs
 1650  sudo apt-get install ukuu -y
 1651  wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.4_amd64.deb
 1652  ppa-purge
 1653  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1654  sudo apt-get update
 1655  sudo aptt update
 1656  sudo apt update
 1657  lsb_release -a
 1658  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1659  ppa: lubuntu-desktop/ppa 
 1660  ppa: lubuntu-desktop/ppa
 1661  lsb_release -a
 1662  ppa: lubuntu-desktop/ppa
 1663  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1664  sudo apt-get update
 1665  clear
 1666  sudo do-release-upgrade -p
 1667  history
```

Comment: 2. and 3. above merely seem to indicate that you are new at compiling software and made normal beginner mistakes. Are you looking for other ways to install Wacom software? Or are you simply looking for help compiling? It's not clear which direction you want answers.

Comment: @user535733 I am looking for some way to install Wacom

Comment: Try to find the    ./configure   where you extracted the package, maybe attempt a cd to the package and re-run the script from there. I've read about the execute bit being set incorrectly for ./configure. You should be able to invoke it with "sh ./configure"  Give that a try.

Comment: @Crabtree I have extracted the package on desktop. Then, what should I do?

Comment: @user535733 that is same as explained in some other page. It did not work

Comment: Thanks K7AAY for edit. It looks better

Comment: You're welcome! Useful editing tips are at http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik please be clear: Did you *understand* the instructions? Did you get stuck on any particular step? Let's start easy: Did you properly download and untar the software?

Comment: @user535733 I have downloaded and unzipped the software in desktop with name input-wacom-0.45.0 I thank you for your time :) :) Please help me to sort this out..

Comment: Did you install the prerequisite packages? `sudo apt install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: try cd Desktop and re-running the script from there. Not sure if that will do anything or not, that's just getting to where you can confirm the ./configure location. besides that - I would try to re-run the script adding "sh " before ./configure

Comment: @user535733 as mentioned above, that gives "
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
autoconf is already the newest version (2.69-11).
linux-headers-4.15.0-72-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0-72.81).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."

Comment: @Crabtree I did ./configure and got "bash: ./configure: No such file or directory" then I did   "sh ./configure" and got  "sh: 0: Can't open ./configure"

Comment: Try right clicking ./configure and going to properties > Permissions > ticking the box that says Allow executing file as program?

Comment: It is already in that mode.. @Crabtree

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Here's something I found. Check the top answer. Good luck with it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158960/can-not-run-configure-command-no-such-file-or-directory

Have you tried running this command under Desktop directory? if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed" (add the sh if fails)

Comment: @Crabtree The page https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Device-IDs says that "The "Linux" column indicates that minimum kernel version that natively supports the tablet". Further it says "You can check your kernel version by running uname -r". I did that and found that, kernel is "4.15.0-72-generic" (please see attached pic in question) where as according to that page, kernel should be minimum 4.16 (please see attached pic question). I think that could be a problem. How do I solve this?

Comment: @Crabtree I did that. no change in theoutput