# Lost Ubuntu and ended up with Lubuntu can not use sudo apt get

Tags: lubuntu

I was trying [probelm in upgrading the kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200485/probelm-in-upgrading-the-kernel/1200492#1200492) and [wacom CTL-472 installation on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (build failure issue)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200466/wacom-ctl-472-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-build-failure-issue?noredirect=1#comment2012783_1200466)

I followed procedure mentioned somewhere and ended up loosing Ubuntu version. Everything changed. Login page now looks as in the attached image.

[image]

Almost everything got uninstalled, for example, Chrome, Kile, Texstudio, adobe reader.

I realised it is in lubuntu version by clicking power button. I am attaching what I see.

[image]

I am also not able to access any of the drives. I realise that I made a mess. How do I clean this?

History of what I have done is :

```
 1506  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1507  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:doctormo/wacom-plus
 1508  sudo apt-get update
 1509  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 1510  sudo apt-get install wacom-dkms
 1511  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1512  clear
 1513  sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 1514  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1515  wacom
 1516  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1517  sudo apt-get install autoconf pkg-config make xutils-dev libtool xserver-xorg-dev$(dpkg -S $(which Xorg) | grep -Eo -- "-hwe-[^:]*") libx11-dev libxi-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libudev-dev
 1518  set -- --prefix="/usr" --libdir="$(readlink -e $(ls -d /usr/lib*/xorg/modules/input/../../../ | head -n1))"
 1519  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh "$@"; else ./configure "$@"; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1520  clear
 1521  sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
 1522  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 1523  sudo apt-get update
 1524  sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
 1525  sudo do-release-upgrade
 1526  sudo ./bionic &
 1527  xsetwacom --list devices 
 1528  sudo rmmod wacom
 1529  sudo rmmod wacom_w8001
 1530  $ if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1531  clear
 1532  sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 1533  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1534  grep "" /sys/module/wacom*/version
 1535  sudo rmmod wacom
 1536  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1537  xinput list
 1538  clear
 1539  sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential 
 1540  sudo apt-get install autoconf                                  
 1541  cd downloads
 1542  cd /downloads
 1543  cd /home
 1544  /downloads
 1545  cd /home
 1546  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1547  modinfo wacom | grep version
 1548  sudo -s 'apt-get update && apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-wacom'
 1549  sudo apt  install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 1550  sudo apt-get install git-core make kernel-package bc
 1551  ls home
 1552  ls /home
 1553  ls Desktop
 1554  cd input-wacom-0.45.0
 1555  /configure
 1556  ./configure
 1557  make
 1558  sudo make install
 1559  clear
 1560  sudo apt install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 1561  cd Desktop
 1562  home
 1563  cd Desktop
 1564  sudo apt install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
 1565  ./configure
 1566  sh ./configure
 1567  xinput list
 1568  uname -r
 1569  cd Desktop
 1570  if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
 1571  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
 1572  sudo apt-get install ukuu
 1573  sudo xhost +
 1574  sudo ukuu
 1575  sudo ukuu --install-latest
 1576  clear
 1577  sudo apt-get update
 1578  sudo apt-get install python-bs4 python-apt
 1579  cd /tmp
 1580  rm -rf medigeek-kmp*
 1581  wget https://github.com/medigeek/kmp-downloader/tarball/master -O kmpd.tar.gz
 1582  tar xzf kmpd.tar.gz
 1583  cd medigeek-*
 1584  python kmpd.py -d
 1585  uname -r
 1586  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
 1587  clear
 1588  uname -r
 1589  lsb_release -a
 1590  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04  
 1591  clear
 1592  lsb_release -a
 1593  uname -mrs
 1594  sudo apt update
 1595  apt-cache search linux-generic
 1596  sudo apt install linux-image-4.xx
 1597  apt-cache search linux-image
 1598  sudo apt install linux-image-4.xx
 1599  clear
 1600  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
 1601  sudo apt-get update
 1602  sudo apt-get install ukuu -y
 1603  ukuu –help
 1604  uname -mrs
 1605  uname -r
 1606  clear
 1607  sudo apt-get autoremove
 1608  ukuu --list
 1609  ukuu
 1610  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
 1611  do-releaseupgrade -c
 1612  do-release-upgrade -c
 1613  /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
 1614  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1615  apt install linux-image-generic
 1616  apt purge linux-image-generic-lts-xenial
 1617  hwe-support-status
 1618  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1619  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1620  clear
 1621  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 1622  sudo do-release-upgrade -p
 1623  sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 1624  lsb_release -a
 1625  sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 1626  clear
 1627  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1628  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 1629  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1630  sudo apt-get clean
 1631  sudo apt-get autoclean
 1632  sudo apt-get -f install
 1633  clear
 1634  sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
 1635  clear
 1636  sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
 1637  clear
 1638  sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
 1639  mkdir ppa-purge && cd ppa-purge && wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/ppa-purge/ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr56_all.deb && wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/a/aptitude/aptitude_0.6.6-1ubuntu1_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i ./*.deb
 1640  sudo ppa-purge ppa:someppa/ppa
 1641  apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
 1642  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
 1643  clear
 1644  sudo apt-get update
 1645  sudo apt-get upgrade
 1646  sudo apt --fix-broken install
 1647  sudo apt-get update
 1648  lsb_release -a
 1649  uname -mrs
 1650  sudo apt-get install ukuu -y
 1651  wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.4_amd64.deb
 1652  ppa-purge
 1653  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1654  sudo apt-get update
 1655  sudo aptt update
 1656  sudo apt update
 1657  lsb_release -a
 1658  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1659  ppa: lubuntu-desktop/ppa 
 1660  ppa: lubuntu-desktop/ppa
 1661  lsb_release -a
 1662  ppa: lubuntu-desktop/ppa
 1663  sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
 1664  sudo apt-get update
 1665  clear
 1666  sudo do-release-upgrade -p
 1667  history
```

In put service --status-all

Outut

```
praphulla@localhost:~$ service --status-all
 [ + ]  acpid
 [ - ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ - ]  apport
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ - ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  brltty
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  cups-browsed
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ - ]  dns-clean
 [ - ]  gdm3
 [ + ]  grub-common
 [ - ]  hwclock.sh
 [ - ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.dpkg-bak
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  lightdm
 [ + ]  lm-sensors
 [ + ]  network-manager
 [ + ]  networking
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ - ]  plymouth-log
 [ - ]  pppd-dns
 [ + ]  procps
 [ + ]  resolvconf
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ - ]  saned
 [ + ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ + ]  thermald
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ - ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ + ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common
```

Comment: What you're seeing is only graphics because you've made changes to your DM (eg. `lightdm`) most likely, or changed `plymouth` screens, and the lubuntu images have just replaced the Ubuntu ones. Your command history, or apt logs will show what you actually did, but at the login screen - you can select another DE using the session selection top right.

Comment: @guiverc can you please explain how to do that.. I am more or less sure that I messed up everything. Can you help me to do one by one..

Comment: The command `history` will display what commands you have executed, logs of what you install/remove via dpkg/apt type tools are found in /var/log/apt/history.log (older history is located in the directory too). To undo what you've done (which I don't know what that is), you need to know what you did first.  My guess is you've become scared because of changes you caused to occur (via commands you didn't understand) that may have changed your *visuals*, eg. DM being used (Ubuntu GNOME's `gdm3` replaced by `lightdm` etc).

Comment: @guiverc I have added the history. please have a look at it

Comment: @guiverc where should I look for it?

Comment: I did service --status-all and written down what I see.. please see above edit @guiverc

Comment: What release are you using?   Why is there are command to switch [archive|security].ubuntu.com to point to old-releases.ubuntu.com?   As already suggested, I'd be tempted to use `ubuntu-support-status` to view your current support status  (I suspect a good% of your system is unsupported), as I suspect I don't have the full story, and from your `history`, I suspect a re-install may be better for you.  *Your service command (I didn't ask for) shows you replaced `gdm3` with `lightdm` as I suspected in prior comments*

Comment: @guiverc Is there a hope to save files on my computer if I reinstall?? I am not able to access files in drives other than home, documents, downloads..

Comment: Yes you can re-install using 'something-else', select your existing partitions & do **not** format. It notes your added packages, erases system directories, installs, adds back your additional packages without touching $HOME.  As most desktop apps store configs etc in /home/... no data should be lost; however some server apps do store conf files in system directories so those can be wiped.  Backups should always be done (from terminal, or using 'live' system). FYI: I need to login to SE to use chat, I'm currently not logged in so cannot 'chat'. My Ubuntu-ONE account only allows access to here

Comment: thank you. I will ask my friend to do as you suggested.. He knows somethings about ubuntu.. with your suggestion it might be easier..